# httpurlconnection is not giving proper response code in case of multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, httpurlconnection

I want to get all urls from given url  and I want to check status of each url.

For that I am using `ExecutorService` for multi-threading to check status of each and every url.

Code of class which check response code for url is given below

```
public class ConnectionTester  implements Callable<Object> {
    private URL url;
    private Map<String,Integer> map;
    private static final Log LOGGER =      
    LogFactoryUtil.getLog(ConnectionTester.class);

    public ConnectionTester(String url,Map<String,Integer> map) {
        try {
            this.url = new URL(url);
            this.map = map;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get status code of url
     * @return
     */
    public void getStatuscode(URL url) {
        HttpURLConnection http = null;
        try {
            http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            http.setConnectTimeout(0);
            http.setReadTimeout(0);
            http.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            http.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;    
            Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)   
            Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36");
            http.connect();
            map.put(url.toString(), http.getResponseCode());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            map.put(url.toString(), 500 );
        }finally{
            if(http !=null)http.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        getStatuscode(url);
        return null;

    }
}
```

And I use following code to check response code for each and every url

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(urls.size());
   List<ConnectionTester> connectionTesters = new ArrayList<ConnectionTester>(urls.size());
   Map<String,Integer> map  = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
   for (String string : urls) {
       if(Validator.isNotNull(string) && !string.contains("mailto"))
           connectionTesters.add(new ConnectionTester(string, map));
   }
   service.invokeAll(connectionTesters);
```

Now problem is when I don't use multi-threading I get proper response code of each and every URL but when I use multi-threading I am getting  connection timeout exception.

So far I have checked and tried below things.

1. My internet speed is high
2. I have set `http.setConnectTimeout(0); http.setReadTimeout(0);` to set infinite time out.
3. Response time of url I am checking is also less and working fine.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: You are overloading the server. Solution: don't.

Comment: Also, there is a shadowing on your method `getStatuscode(URL url)` The attribute `url` is also defined for the class.

Comment: Probably many of the URL's are for the same server, so it may be rejecting requests.  It can also be that you are hitting the standard limits of X connections to the same domain that is built in.

Comment: Also: you need to synchronize access to the `map` when you do it from several threads.

Comment: If you are getting a response from the server, code 500 in this case, then this connection is working fine. Http response code 500, means there is a problem on the server. Check the server log for errors

Comment: @john16384, all urls are for same server. How can I check connections limit to same domain that is built in ?

Comment: @MadPiranha. No I am not getting response code 500 but I am getting connection timeout exception.

Comment: @Kanan, Please update the question, in that case.

Comment: The setting I'm referring to is `http.maxConnections`, a system property, which by default is 5.  It is for persistent connections, but this may be interfering.

Comment: Im assuming that all url strings are different but, addressing the same server. What is the size of the urls list ?

Comment: @MadPiranha , url strings are different and not all but most of the urls are addressing same server . Size of the urls list vary from 150 to 200.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with this code that will cause the timeout. You can try this by creating a dummy urls list and hitting any server other than yours. Looks like your server cannot handle the load. 
Let me know if this code results in a timeout.
_Prefix this to your code to create_ *urls*
`List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>(); for(int i=0;i<500;i++){ urls.add("http://urlecho.appspot.com/echo?status=200&Content-Type=text%2Fhtml&body=Hello%20world" + (i+1));}`

Answer (score 1):

You are overloading the server. When a Unix/Linux TCP server's *listen(2)* backlog queue fills, it starts ignoring incoming connect requests, which causes connect timeouts at the clients.

Solution: don't. Cut the number of threads, and when a thread gets a connect timeout, don't create any more.

Comment: May be you are right but then how will it be possible to check status of more urls in minimum time ? . I don't see any way other than multi-threading.

Comment: No 'maybe' about it.That is how the backlog queue behaves.The way to do it is not to overload the server, as I have already stated. 'Minimum time' has no meaning if your idea of 'minimum' is going to cause errors. You can't go faster than the server will let you.