# How to stop Connection timeouts when requesting data from API

Tags: java, connection-timeout

I'm working with an API that gets data of ufo sighting incidents.
I am trying to find out how many suspected hoaxes there are within an `ArrayList` of `Incident`s that has each ufo incident within a given time frame.

Here is the code snippet:

```
for (Incident i : incidents)
    {
        try {
            b = API.getIncidentDetails(i.getIncidentID()).toLowerCase().contains("hoax");
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    if (b)
    {
        ++hoaxes;
    }
```

I thought it would be easy to just loop through the array and check if the incident description `getIncidentDetails` had the word `hoax` in it, but it turns out that the `getIncidentDetails` method of the API is making requests to a server (unsurprisingly), and me calling the method several times per second ends up overloading the server (I think) and causing a `ConnectException` timeout. The inner workings of the API are not available for me to edit so I can't manually deal with how the requests are made.

Here is the error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at api.ufo.Connection.sendRESTfulQuery(Connection.java:83)
at api.ufo.API.getIncidentDetails(API.java:105)
```

And here is line 83 in Connection:

```
  url = null;sslFactory = null; label267: try { wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
```

`con` is a HttpsURLConnection instance.

EDIT: This is all the code relaing to `con` in the class. Sensitive info replaced with omittedURL; they are all identical. I don't know much about connections and connection pooling but from what a few google searches has told me it doesn't look like pooling is being used, and also doesn't look like the connection gets closed.

```
  HttpURLConnection con;
  HttpURLConnection con;
  if ("omittedURL".contains("localhost"))
  {

    URL url = new URL("http://omittedURL/" + query);

    con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
  }
  else
  {
    url = new URL("https://omittedURL/" + query);

    sslFactory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

    con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

    ((HttpsURLConnection)con).setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory);
  }


  con.setRequestMethod("POST");

  con.setDoOutput(true);

  url = null;sslFactory = null; label267: try { wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
  }
  finally {
    DataOutputStream wr;
    url = sslFactory; break label267; if (url != sslFactory) url.addSuppressed(sslFactory);
  }
  if (con.getResponseCode() != 200)
  {
    System.err.println("API Response Error Code: " + con.getResponseCode());
  }


  return Utils.processJSONInputStream(con.getInputStream());
```

END EDIT

I thought I could use `Thread.sleep` to have a little delay between each request, but setting a delay too small does not fix the problem and setting a delay too big ends up with the user waiting several minutes before data gets displayed.

Instead I just made it wait 3 seconds if it times out, but 3 seconds doesn't seem to be long enough to stop the next few requests from timing out or taking too long. I tried 15 seconds but it didn't make much difference. It usually goes through 200-400 requests before requests start taking 1000+ milliseconds to complete, and then times out. `incidents` usually has 5000+ `Incident`s, and requests take 32 milliseconds on average.

**At the moment it is taking 10mins+ to loop through ~5000 method calls to `getIncidentDetails` which is by far too long. I want to be able to trim it down to an average 3-5 minutes.**

I had an idea of having one `Thread` make the requests and another `Thread` checking if the request was taking too long and then `interrupt`ing the requesting `Thread`, but I have no idea how to implement it because unfortunately I am still a noob. If this is a good idea please gimme some tips on how to get it done.

Thanks for reading. If you need more information please ask.

Comment: Can you check if the `connection` used to pull the incidents is getting closed or returned to the pool (if it's using connection pooling). The way you are describing it, it sounds like there's a problem with the connections available, although there may be other problems. However this is where I would start my troubleshooting, given the info you have provided.

Comment: Duplicate of [HttpURLConnection is not giving proper response code in case of multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42849629/httpurlconnection-is-not-giving-proper-response-code-in-case-of-multithreading/42850453#comment72808597_42850453).

Comment: You could use Java 8 [parallel or parallelStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) to concurrently call your API. I also like the unix tool gnu parallel [(see examples)](https://www.msi.umn.edu/support/faq/how-can-i-use-gnu-parallel-run-lot-commands-parallel) It allows you to run small pieces of code 'in parallel'.